# Firebase: Error (auth/missing-email) when the email definetly exists. Reactjs

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

Here is my code:

```
function loginWithEmailHandler() {
        signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth)
        .then((result) => {
            const user = result.user;
            console.log(user.email, user.displayName);
            navigate("/");
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            const errorCode = error.code;
            const errorMessage = error.message;
            setMode("INCORRECT");
            console.log(errorCode, errorMessage);
        });
    }
```

When I run this function in my LoginForm.js it gives the error stated in the title. I don't know how I could check if it checking for the correct email or not so I am a bit stuck here.

Comment: The `signInWithEmailAndPassword()` takes 3 parameters - auth instance, email and password. But you are passing only the first one. Can you change it to `ignInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, userEmail, userPassword)` and make sure you are passing correct values?

Comment: Sounds like an answer @Dharmaraj :)

Comment: When I add those it gives an error saying they aren't defined. Wait that is most likely because I am not passing the correct values. sorry.

Comment: Thanks @FrankvanPuffelen :) I just wanted to confirm if OP had missed copying any params here 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `signInWithEmailAndPassword()` takes 3 parameters - auth instance, email and password. But you are passing only the first one. Try refactoring the code as shown below:

```
function loginWithEmailHandler(email, password) {
  signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
    .then((result) => {
      const user = result.user;
      console.log(user.email, user.displayName);
      navigate("/");
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      const errorCode = error.code;
      const errorMessage = error.message;
      setMode("INCORRECT");
      console.log(errorCode, errorMessage);
    });
}
```

Make sure you pass the email and password entered by the user in that function:

```
// While calling the function
loginWithEmailHandler('user@domain.tld', 'userPassword');
```

You can read more in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth#sign_in_a_user_with_an_email_address_and_password).